# Python logging. Update log entry

Tags: python, logging

I want to create a log table with columns `process`, `status`, `start_time` and `end_time`.
From the start of process I create entry with `status` *"In progress"*, after process is done I want to set `end_time` and update `status` on *fail/success*.

Is there a way to do it with logging library or other labraries?

UPD: I am using logging library now. For now I came up with creating custom logger class, where I create unique record_id, put it in log and return. Then when the logger fires next time it might accept record_id field, that's how I keep track of log entries.

But now I have another problem, which I described here -> [Python logging. Use fileConfig and setLoggerClass together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754346/python-logging-use-fileconfig-and-setloggerclass-together)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module?

Answer (score 1):

for logging in python you can use python's standard logging module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html