# Python logging. Use fileConfig and setLoggerClass together

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have created a custom logger class and descripbed loggers config in config.cfg file.
When I loaded config and set logger class to my custom class the logger chosen from getLogger is still default logger.

Generally I want different loggers for different event and I don't want logging in third party libraries conflicting with my custom logger.

My config:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,fileLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler, dbHandler

[formatters]
keys=standardFormatter

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=

[logger_fileLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler
qualname=root.fileLogger
propagate=0

[logger_dbLogger]
level=INFO
handlers=dbHandler
qualname=dbLogger
propagate=1

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=NOTSET
formatter=standardFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=standardFormatter
args=('log.log',)

[handler_dbHandler]
class=loggers.handlers.db_handler.DBHandler
level=INFO
formatter=standardFormatter
args=()

[formatter_standardFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s; %(record_id)s; %(levelname)s; %(mdl)s; %(obj)s; %(status)s; %(message)s
datefmt=%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S
```

Usage

```
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig
from loggers.custom_logger import CustomLogger

logging.setLoggerClass(CustomLogger)
fileConfig('loggers/config.cfg')

logger = logging.getLogger('root.fileLogger')
logger.info('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Custom logger accepts bunch of arguments and works fine for loggers created with names that are not in the config file, however for the name 'root.fileLogger' the output of the code above is

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1083, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 927, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 663, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 367, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Message: 'A'
Arguments: ('B', 'C')
```

Any ideas why it happens and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that %(record_id) is not available in the non-custom context, so the logger internally raises a `KeyError` when trying to interpolate the formatting string.

Comment: But it is available in custom context and I need to use loggers described in config file with custom logger class